# How do you set the delegate when passing data from ViewController to View?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

Here's the relevant code:

**in ViewController**

```
protocol LocationDelegate {

    func setLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
}

var locationDelegate: LocationDelegate?

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    locationDelegate?.setLocation(coordinate: coordinate)

    createPostView = createViewFromNib()
    createPostView.center = SCREEN_CENTER_POSITION
    self.view.addSubview(createPostView)
}
```

**in CreatePostView**

```
class CreatePostView: UIView, UINavigationControllerDelegate, LocationDelegate {

 var location: CLLocation! = CLLocation()

 func setLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    self.location = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
 }

}
```

This doesn't work. "location" is always being saved as empty and I believe it's because I haven't set the delegate. I know this is usually done in prepareForSegue when passing data between two ViewControllers, but in this case, I'm not sure when to set it. How should I go about this?

Comment: Where/How do you create a `CreatePostView` object?

Comment: CreatePostView is a custom view created when the user long presses on the mapView. How I call it is shown above (it's an XIB).

Comment: Is there only ever one of them at a time?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Once it's dismissed I set the View to nil so there's always only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused about how the delegate pattern works.

If I understand what you are trying to do... In `ViewController` you are accepting a longPress on the mapView, which is also passing the `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. You then create a `CreatePostView` which you want to add to your view as a subview... and you want to set the `location` var in that `createPostView` instance to the long-press coordinate. Correct?

If so, you don't need the delegate at all.

Instead, your `CreatePostView` class should have:

```
class CreatePostView: UIView, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var location: CLLocation! = CLLocation()

    func setLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        self.location = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

    }

}
```

and your `ViewController` class should have:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    // instantiate your CreatePostView
    createPostView = createViewFromNib()

    // set it's .center property
    createPostView.center = SCREEN_CENTER_POSITION

    // here is where you "pass in" the coordinate
    createPostView.setLocation(coordinate: coordinate)

    // add it to your view
    self.view.addSubview(createPostView)

}
```

You would want to use a delegate pattern if, for example, your `createPostView` had text fields and buttons, and you want to pass *those* values "up" to your ViewController.

Comment: Thanks! This works. Thanks also for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    createPostView = createViewFromNib() as! CreatePostView
    createPostView.setLocation(coordinate: coordinate)
    createPostView.center = SCREEN_CENTER_POSITION
    self.view.addSubview(createPostView)
}
```

Comment: It didn't work; the setLocation function still isn't called and location is not saved.

Comment: Try the edit above. You don't even seem to need the delegate.